# Compile Blitz++ with Mingw64

Tags: mingw, blitz++

I'm on a Win7 64Bit system and I want to compile the Blitz++ library with mingw64. I am facing some problem, since the readme file of the Blitz++ library states that i have to run ./confiugre which I can't on Win, right?

So, who can point me in the right direction?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it from the MSYS shell .MSYS tries to emulate a *Nix shell.You should have installed MSYS with MINGW, if not use the MINGW installer for that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have used http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/ to install mingw64. I can't find MSYS there. That's because I couldn't find an official installer for MING64 (I only found the sources). I'm a bit lost at the moment.

Comment: Did you try this? http://code.google.com/p/tonatiuh/wiki/InstallingMinGWForWindows64

Comment: If you don't want to reinstall all the stuff :on TDM page it is said that MSYS works well with TDM-GCC. So on the wiki page from my previous comment , skip the Mingw install and only do the install MSYS and the postinstall steps

Comment: Great thanks, that really helpd a lot. Now I can run the configure script.

Comment: Just another question, I have seen that i can install mingw in cygwin. Is this then the same setup as the standalone mingw?

Comment: Glad it helped.As of Cygwin I never installed it alongside MingW but the MinGw FAQ (http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ) has hints on how to do it (see:How do I use MinGW with Cygwin). If that does'nt do it, maybe you should ask a new question to get attention from someone who already did such an install.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was just curious - for now I use Mingw with MSYS as you suggested.